# Postgres XML parsing - Calculate the sum of multiple nodes of the same name using XPath

Tags: postgresql, xpath

I have an xml snippet as below:

```
<OpCodeLaborInfo JobStatus="F" UpSellFlag="N" JobNo="1" OpCode="02TTZ10K" OpCodeDesc="10K SERVICE">
      <TechInfo ActualHrsWorked="2.50" CustTechRate="27.00" TechHrs="0.00" TechName="JEFF SELLERS" TechNo="4816" />
      <TechInfo ActualHrsWorked="0.00" CustTechRate="27.00" TechHrs="0.70" TechName="JEFF SELLERS" TechNo="4816" />
      <BillTimeRateHrs BillRate="129.97" />
      <CCCStmts Correction="PERFORMED 10K SERVICE" Complaint="LUBE OIL FILTER CHANGE, TIRE ROTATION, PERFORM MULTI POINT" />
      <CCCStmts Correction="X" Complaint="INSPECTION, INSPECT FILTERS AND RECOMMEND, INSPECT BRAKES," />
                    <CCCStmts Complaint="BELTS AND HOSES" />
      <RoAmts DlrCost="18.90" PayType="Cust" AmtType="Job" TotalAmt="59.12" />
</OpCodeLaborInfo>
<OpCodeLaborInfo JobStatus="F" UpSellFlag="N" JobNo="2" OpCode="02TTZ10K" OpCodeDesc="10K SERVICE">
          <TechInfo ActualHrsWorked="2.50" CustTechRate="27.00" TechHrs="1.00" TechName="JEFF SELLERS" TechNo="4816" />
          <TechInfo ActualHrsWorked="0.00" CustTechRate="27.00" TechHrs="0.00" TechName="JEFF SELLERS" TechNo="4816" />
          <BillTimeRateHrs BillRate="129.97" />
          <CCCStmts Correction="PERFORMED 10K SERVICE" Complaint="LUBE OIL FILTER CHANGE, TIRE ROTATION, PERFORM MULTI POINT" />
          <CCCStmts Correction="X" Complaint="INSPECTION, INSPECT FILTERS AND RECOMMEND, INSPECT BRAKES," />
          <CCCStmts Complaint="BELTS AND HOSES" />
          <RoAmts DlrCost="18.90" PayType="Cust" AmtType="Job" TotalAmt="59.12" />
</OpCodeLaborInfo>
```

I need to calculate the sum of the TechInfo/@TechHrs for each OpCodeLaborInfo. I tried the following:

```
unnest(xpath('sum(//dns:RepairOrder/dns:RoRecord/dns:Rolabor/dns:OpCodeLaborInfo/dns:TechInfo/@TechHrs[1])'::text,
      data_detail.ro_data_xml, 
      ARRAY[ARRAY['dns'::text, 'http://www.starstandards.org/STAR'::text]]))::text::numeric AS lbrsoldhours
```

but this seems to return the sum of the Tech Hours inside both the OpCodeLaborInfo nodes. Could someone be able to tell me how I can tweak the xpath so as to get the desired result.

So basically I need :

| Job | Tech Hrs |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | sum(0.00+0.70) |
| 2 | sum(1.00+0.00) |

Comment: Is that XML (both tags) part of a single row's column? Or does this represent two rows in a table?

Comment: Each <OpCodeLaborInfo> is a table row and I need the sum of the two TechInfo/@TechHrs nodes as a column in each row.

Comment: which means I will have two rows as below:

Comment: Job     TechHrs
 1        sum(0.00+0.70)
 2        sum(1.00+0.00)

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this using `xmltable()`

```
select d.job, sum(t.hours)
from data_detail d
  cross join xmltable (
                '/OpCodeLaborInfo/TechInfo'
                passing d.ro_data_xml
                columns hours numeric path '@TechHrs') as t
group by d.job;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5ba92c45ef54d0fffe48e93dbb17c392)

---

The XPath is probably not correct as the XPath you have shown doesn't match your sample XML data. Your sample XML also doesn't contain a namespace, so I am not sure why you are passing one to `xpath()`

But if you need one, you can use something like this:

```
  cross join xmltable (
                xmlnamespaces ('http://www.starstandards.org/STAR' as dns),
                '/dns:OpCodeLaborInfo/dns:TechInfo'
                passing d.ro_data_xml
                columns hours numeric path '@TechHrs') as t
```

Comment: Your solution is using two records with XML documents, instead of a single XML document. That only works when you have different documents

Comment: @FrankHeikens: see the comments under the question. Priya Sooraj stated that "*Each <OpCodeLaborInfo> is a table row*"

Comment: I completely missed that part... :-(

Comment: @FrankHeikens: but this solution can easily be adjusted in case the tags are really in a single XML value: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e350b62b313e705f727447d66294a145

Answer (score 0):

xpath can also work fine:

```
SELECT  job
    , SUM((xpath('//@TechHrs', element))[1]::text::decimal)
FROM    data_detail
  , LATERAL (SELECT unnest(xpath('/OpCodeLaborInfo/TechInfo', ro_data_xml))) u(element)
GROUP BY job;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a9a9aa06c7ec5c4c6f652f374b1123f4)

(based on the fiddle of @a_horse_with_no_name)